# button click to search multiple Access tables

Tags: c#

I have a simple feature to search an Access table for a given serial number by button click.

Is there a way to add to what I have below to search multiple tables for the serial number and display in datagridview?

```
private void searchItembtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(serialSearch.Text))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;

                command.Parameters.Add("@searchSerial", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = serialSearch.Text;
                string searchFB = "SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE SerialNumber = @searchSerial";
                command.CommandText = searchFB;

                connection.Close();
                OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                db.Fill(dt);
                dataGridFB.DataSource = dt;

            }

            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                connection.Close();
            }
            searchHide();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or exception?? what is wrong with your code??

Comment: No, this code works perfect. It searches (1) table for a given serial number. I want to find out if there is a way to search more than (1) table at a time.

Comment: @CamlCase: Is there any relations with those table that you need to check?

Comment: if tables are related then you can try join in select query

Comment: Well, I have three tables in which the user may find a certain serial number. There are three different forms with search functions. I am trying to create one search function from the first form that will search all three tables.